# Undistort image from given calibration data in OpenCV C++

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing

I have an image as `Foam_Image.jpg`, from which I want to remove the fisheye distortion. I already have the camera calibration data within my `calibration_data.xml` file. I am really a newbie in C++ and I've heard about the  `undistort` function, but I don't know how can I apply it in OpenCV C++. Could anyone give me an idea?

Answer (score 5):

How did you create your `calibration_data.xml`?

What did you try so far?

I will assume it contains the information you obtained from the chessboard calibration of OpenCV like this one

```
// Extract chessboard
vector<vector<Point3f>> object_points;
vector<vector<Point2f>> image_points;

// ...

bool found = findChessboardCorners(image, board_sz, corners, CV_CALIB_CB_ADAPTIVE_THRESH | CV_CALIB_CB_FILTER_QUADS);

// ...

// Compute intrinsic camera parameters.
vector<Mat> rvecs;
vector<Mat> tvecs;
calibrateCamera(object_points, image_points, image.size(), Camera_Matrix, Distortion_Coefficients, rvecs, tvecs);

// Store results to calibration_data.xml
```

Then images can be un-distorted using [`undistort()`](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/geometric_transformations.html#void%20undistort%28InputArray%20src,%20OutputArray%20dst,%20InputArray%20cameraMatrix,%20InputArray%20distCoeffs,%20InputArray%20newCameraMatrix%29) like this

```
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>

// ...

Mat Camera_Matrix;           // From calibration_data.xml
Mat Distortion_Coefficients; // From calibration_data.xml

cv::Mat image = cv::imread( "Foam_Image,jpg" );
cv::Mat imageUndistorted; // Will be the undistorted version of the above image.

undistort(image, imageUndistorted, Camera_Matrix, Distortion_Coefficients);

// ...
```

I took the information above from [aishack.in](http://www.aishack.in/tutorials/calibrating-undistorting-with-opencv-in-c-oh-yeah/) and if you search for it on the web (or on SO) will find many more detailed tutorials.

Comment: So, instead of `image` I consider `Foam_Image.jpg`, and instead of `imageUndistorted` I can give any name in a bitmap format? I have the following matrices from the calibration: `Camera_Matrix`, `Distortion_Coefficients`, `Per_View_Reprojection_Errors`, `Extrinsic_Parameters` and `Image_Points`. I got the calibration data from someone else, so I didn't do the calibration.

Comment: `image` is the name of a variable. You need to initialize it, e.g. by loading your image in to it: `image = cv::imread( "Foam_Image.jpg" );`

Comment: Right, thank you. Yes, I tried to read my image using `cv::Mat image = cv::imread("Foam_Image.jpg", CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE);` and the compilation goes fine of course, but the building gives me an error like `undefined reference to cv::imread(cv::String const&, int)`. Maybe is something wrong with the header files in opencv, I really don't know.

Comment: That's probably because you forgot to link `opencv_highgui`. You should ask a separate question for that problem, though.

Comment: No, I did do `#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>`, but I still have the error.

Comment: You mix up the terminology. Though, you include the header file you probably do not link the corresponding DLL/SO into your program. Anyway, comments should not be used for lengthy discussions. Please ask a new question.